# MariaDB: My Store Procedure Did Not Return Any Row

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb, union

I've create store procedure with parameters in mariaDB. When I call the store procedure its return empty row although every single tables contains many data. This is the result when I make a call:
call sp_rpt_trans('2020','10');
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.141 sec. */

Below is my code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_rpt_trans (_year VARCHAR(10),_month VARCHAR(10))

BEGIN

create TEMPORARY table if not exists rpt_trans1 ( 
   category varchar(100) NULL,
   pos VARCHAR(40) NULL,
   id VARCHAR(40) NULL,
   description VARCHAR(100) NULL,
   created_on datetime NULL,    
   handling_fee_amt DECIMAL(22,6) NULL,
   amt DECIMAL(22,6) NULL,
   outlet_commission DECIMAL(22,6) NULL,
   weight DECIMAL(10,2) NULL
);

insert into rpt_trans1 (
category, pos, id, description, created_on, handling_fee_amt, amt, outlet_commission, weight)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            'courier' AS category,
            pt.id pos,
            o.id,
            o.description,
            pt.created_on,
            ct.handling_fee_amt,
            ct.cour_amt AS amt,
            ct.outlet_commission,
            ct.weight
        from
            pos_trans pt
            inner join mgt_outlet o on o.id = pt.mgt_outlet_id
            and date_format(pt.created_on, '%Y') = _year
            AND date_format(pt.created_on, '%m') = _month
            inner join pos_trans_dt ptd on pt.id = ptd.pos_trans_id
            inner join cour_trans ct on ct.id = ptd.cour_trans_id
            AND ct.mgt_outlet_id = o.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'bill' AS category,
            pt.id pos,
            o.id,
            o.description,
            pt.created_on,
            bt.handling_fee_amt,
            bt.amount AS amt,
            bt.outlet_commission,
            0 as weight
        from
            pos_trans pt
            inner join mgt_outlet o on o.id = pt.mgt_outlet_id
            and date_format(pt.created_on, '%Y') = _year
            AND date_format(pt.created_on, '%m') = _month
            inner join pos_trans_dt ptd on pt.id = ptd.pos_trans_id
            inner join bill_trans bt on bt.id = ptd.bill_trans_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'insurance' AS category,
            pt.id pos,
            o.id,
            o.description,
            pt.created_on,
            0 AS handling_fee_amt,
            ins.amount AS amt,
            ins.outlet_commision,
            0 as weight
        from
            pos_trans pt
            inner join mgt_outlet o on o.id = pt.mgt_outlet_id
            and date_format(pt.created_on, '%Y') = _year
            AND date_format(pt.created_on, '%m') = _month
            inner join pos_trans_dt ptd on pt.id = ptd.pos_trans_id
            inner join ins_trans ins on ins.id = ptd.ins_trans_id
    ) com1
where
    date_format(created_on, '%Y') = _year
    AND date_format(created_on, '%m') = _month
ORDER BY
    created_on ;

TRUNCATE TABLE rpt_trans1 ;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists rpt_trans1 ;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

What is the cause?
Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You insert data into temptable, then truncate this data, then drop temptable. That's all you do. If you need SP to select something than you must select into output stream, not to a table. Now your SP do nothing (except forcing the server to do unnecessary work which' result is not used).

Comment: Thanks for response. What do u mean by "...select into output stream, not to a table". I don't understand. Can you give me some example?

Comment: `SELECT {columns} INTO {table} FROM ...` selects into a table. `SELECT {columns} FROM ...` (without INTO clause) selects into output stream. So simply either remove temptable creation and INSERT clause or add `SELECT * FROM rpt_trans1;` before truncation (but I do not see the reason in this intermediate temptable).

Comment: It's work. I need to select the temp table back to get the value. The reason I create temptable because of reporting. Is there a different in term of performance between call store procedure and select in views?

Comment: *The reason I create temptable because of reporting.* But then you remove it - so you do not use it. In this case making hard copy of selected data makes no sense, single SELECT will give the same everything. *Is there a different in term of performance between call store procedure and select in views?* In this case - no. SPs must be used in more complex cases.